# How to write Fermat's Last Theorem using quantifiers?

Tags: quantifiers

How do I write Fermat's Last Theorem using only universal and existential quantifiers.

I only want to quantify it over the natural numbers (excluding zero)- for which I use $ℤ+$ to represent this set.  My attempt at it, which I don't think is right, is this:

$∀(x∈ℤ+) ∀(y∈ℤ+) ∀(z∈ℤ+) ∃(n∈ℤ+) (x^n+y^n=z^n → n<3)$

Comment: can't you negate the existential? I would go with $$\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}_+,\quad \nexists n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 3},\quad x^n+y^n=z^n.$$

Comment: I think the $\exists n$ should be $\forall n$, like: $∀(x∈ℤ+) ∀(y∈ℤ+) ∀(z∈ℤ+) ∀(n∈ℤ+) (x^n+y^n=z^n → n<3)$. It says, whatever $x,y,z,n$ are, IF $x^n+y^n=z^n$ THEN $n$ must be at most $2$.

Comment: Yes, what Mirko says!

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.  It's been 20+ years since I've done this and the memory of it is a little clouded- but from your answers and thinking more about it I've got it.